# How to setup MATLAB shape function solver

Tags: matlab, finite-element-analysis

I am trying to find the shape function for a finite element analysis problem in MATLAB. The basic shape function looks like, with the boundary condition on the left. At Ni=N1, x=x1, y=y1 (the coordinate of node 1), the shape function would be equal to 1, when Ni=N1, but x=x2,y=y2 (the coordinate of node 2), the shape function would be 0, and so on and similar at Ni=N2,N3 and such. I use a symbolic 16*16 matrix named A to represent the 4 coefficients at the four shape functions.
[image: shape function for quad element]

This is my code to find the alpha, beta, gamma, and that last greek letter for the four equation from N1 to N4 (totally 16 unknown):

```
A = sym('A', [4 4]);
eqns = zeros(4,4);
coorx = sym('coorx', [1 4]);
coory = sym('coory', [1 4]);
for i=1:4
    for j=1:4
        if j==i
           eqns(i,j)=A(i,1)+A(i,2)*coorx(j)+A(i,3)*coory(j)+A(i,4)*coorx(j)*coory(j)==1;
        else
           eqns(i,j)=A(i,1)+A(i,2)*coorx(j)+A(i,3)*coory(j)+A(i,4)*coorx(j)*coory(j)==0;
        end
    end
end
tst=solve(eqns,A);
tst.A4_4
```

I tested out a lot of outputs, but the only value I got is 0 when I should get a function of sorts like coorx(j)-coory(j). Could you tell me why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are easy to write if you use parametric coordinates and shape functions.  The usual order is to start at the lower left corner and proceed in a counterclockwise direction:

```
-1 <= a <= +1
-1 <= b <= +1

h1(a, b) = (1-a)*(1-b)/4.0
h2(a, b) = (1+a)*(1-b)/4.0
h3(a, b) = (1+a)*(1+b)/4.0
h4(a, b) = (1-a)*(1+b)/4.0
```

You use the Jacobean matrix to map from parametric to global coordinates.